# How to set value to @Html.TextBox() in ASP.NET C# using @Viewbag in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, textbox

I wanted to set a data into the html textbox. I've tried this code:

```
 @Html.TextBox("LastName", @value = @ViewBag.FBUserLastName, new { @style = "width: 300px;", @id = "LastName" })
```

Unfortunately, it showed an error.
I've based that code from this 
[Value not set via ViewData dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241682/asp-net-mvc-html-textbox-value-not-set-via-viewdata-dictionary)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
@Html.TextBox("LastName", 
   (string)ViewBag.FBUserLastName, 
   new { @style = "width: 300px;", @id = "LastName" })
```

You don't need the `@value`.

Also, you don't need the `@` in front of `ViewBag`, because since you've already called `@Html.TextBox`, it is already looking for code.

You also apparently need to cast the ViewBag property to a string.

Comment: I got this error : Compilation Error 

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'TextBox' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: @Roberto, see update. Cast the ViewBag.FBUserLastName to a string

Comment: @Roberto, no problem. If this solved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer when you are able.

Comment: This is not working for me. No mattere what value i set to ViewBag.FBUserLastName , my textbox is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBox(
  "LastName", 
  ViewBag.FBUserLastName, 
  new { @style = "width: 300px;"})
```

It's a function. The second parameter is the value. Also you can leave the @id from the anonymous type because it's passed in the first parameter.

Comment: I got this error : Compilation Error 

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'TextBox' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: That's my fault. Brandon got it right. I forgot to cast it to string